# Как правильно: познания в чем-либо или познания по чему-либо?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Моя знакомая, которая долго живет во Франции, попыталась блеснуть своим знанием русского языка и написала:
 "У тебя...с учетом моих скромных познаний во французском языке. Но с русским, надеюсь, все хорошо..."
**Так как правильно: познания ВО французском языке или ПО французскому языку?**

К какому правилу ее отослать, чтобы она разобралась, как же все-таки грамотно?...

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: с учетом моих скромных **познаний во французском языке** или с учетом моих скромных **знаний по французскому языку**.

**Из словаря**

**ЗНАНИЕ**; 2. только мн.: знания. Совокупность сведений, познаний в какой-л. области человеческой деятельности; обладание сведениями о чём-л. **Знания по архитектуре.**

**ПОЗНАНИЕ**, 3. мн.: познания,  Совокупность знаний в какой-л. области. Приобрести познания **в архитектуре.** Иметь некоторые познания в немецком языке. Проверить познания ученика в орфографии.